# Convert to basic for loop

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue, huffman-code

Can someone help me understand this for loop and convert it to the basic form that I am used to please?

We are given

```
for(vector<CFreq>::iterator it = frequencies.begin(); it != frequencies.end(); i++) 
{
HuffmanTree *node = new HuffmanTree(it->c, it->freq);
queue.push(node);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't get much more basic than that, really. Get used to it, I guess.

Comment: *convert it to the basic form that I am used to* -- We don't know "what you're used to".  In any event, every C++ programmer should be able to readily understand that loop with no issues.

Comment: Trying to understand this loop, and trying to translate it into a more familiar form (which I suppose is `for(int i=0; i<frequencies.size(); ++i)...`) are two different goals. I recommend the former.

Comment: check [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

Answer (score 2):

You can write the loop as a range-based loop as follows:

```
for (const CFreq& f : frequencies) {
  queue.push(new HuffmanTree(f.c, f.freq));
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying "vector<char_freq>" has no member name c and no member named freq. How can I fix that?

Comment: @splattered: are you sure you typed it right, and you didn't say `frequencies` instead of `f`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a loop by accessing the vector by index, you can try this:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < frequencies.size(); i++) {
   queue.push(new HuffmanTree(frequencies[i].c, frequencies[i].freq));
}
```

Comment: 1) `int i` should be `size_t i`.  2) You don't need `node=`, just `queue.push(new HuffmanTree(frequencies[i].c, frequencies[i].freq));`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, out of curiosity, is it bad having to declare a pointer variable before push? what are the disadvantages?

Comment: @splattered, I rather prefer Kerrek's answer above. much simpler.

Comment: @codekaizer: variables are generally bad, because if something varies, you need to think about it. Fewer variables means fewer things to think about. (At the extreme end of this thought process you have functional programming, where nothing varies. Ish.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, true. that's also my rule of thumb. is it like a good practice to just directly have all `new` commands as a parameter to the function?
like: `func(new A(), new B(), new C())`?

Comment: @codekaizer: you wouldn't ever have `new` in good C++; but you could certainly have multiple, say, `make_unique` subexpressions: `f(std::make_unique<A>(x1, x2, x3), std::make_unique<B>(y1, y2))` etc. That'd be much better than creating a variable and then move from it (e.g. you entirely avoid use-after-move bugs).

Comment: @KerrekSB, thank you for this added knowledge: to use `make_unique` instead!